# Form fields not working on checkout page for mobile view in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to setup a WooCoomerce website and everything works fine on desktop view. But form fields are not working on checkout page for mobile view in woocommerce. They used to work previously so I guess this might be an issue with the WooCommerce update some days back , I don't remember if I did update. I checked the code but it looks good. Not sure why it is not working on mobile view. Only billing and shipping form fields are not working, payment gateway fields are working fine too. I used a plugin previously which I disabled now but still the issue is not fixed. Here is the webpage if you want to take a look https://www.love2home.com/checkout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This element is overlapping the content:

```
<h6>Upload an image to use for photo frames or gifts</h6>
```

That is probably why you cannot click it.

Give it a fixed height or cleaarfix maybe.

CSS:

```
#wufdc_div h6 {height:100px;}
```

Comment: yeah you are right, didn't apply css but I disabled the plugin associated with it and looks good now :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In a quick glance I could see that the container "#wufdc_div" occupies almost the entire height of the form.

I hope you serve the following change:

```
#wufdc_div{ position: static; }
```